# Patent DE4038611 A1 - request

Tags: search

I would like to ask for a contact to patent DE4038611 A1 (Mr.Bojanovsky).

Comment: Not quite sure I can agree with the duplicate. The question referenced above explains how to find the inventor of a US patent. This question refers to a German (DE) patent application.

Answer (score 0):

You can look up German patent data in DPMARegister:
https://register.dpma.de/DPMAregister/pat/einsteiger?lang=en

There you will find the full name and registered city of residence of the inventor.

However, note that DE4038611 A1 is merely a published patent application (hence the A1 kind code). No patent was ever granted based on this application, the status of which is "lapsed". I would therefore guess that even the city listed in DPMARegister may not be correct anymore.

In fact, no search report was ever established because the applicant stopped paying the required annual fees.